# Re-publish of existing Python Azure Function has deleted the existing function entirely

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I have successfully published an Azure Function App to Azure (a Python function) using the following command:

```
(.env) PS C:\temp\python_function> func azure functionapp publish httpgengraph --build-native-deps --publish-local-settings -i
```

I made some code changes locally and re-published using the same exact command, except now my function has vanished? The function app is there, 'httpGenGraph' but the actual function is completely missing? E.g it now displays 'You have created a function app, now it's time to add your code' as though there's no code? :(

[image]

What did I do wrong? Output from publishing:

```
(.env) PS C:\temp\python_function> func azure functionapp publish httpgengraph --build-native-deps --publish-local-settings -i

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.225-preview+g5ebeba52a1 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 86.25 ms for C:\temp\python_function\extensions.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.600-preview-009426\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(143,5): message NETSDK1057: You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452 [C:\temp\python_function\extensions.csproj]
  extensions -> C:\temp\python_function\bin\extensions.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.27


Getting site publishing info...
Running 'docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0.12309'....done
Running 'docker run --rm -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:2.0.12309'..done
Running 'docker exec -t b6a2c0 mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot/'..done
Running 'docker cp "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Local\Temp\ldmmjvea.loo/." b6a2c0:"/home/site/wwwroot"'.................done
Running 'docker cp "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8510.tmp" b6a2c0:"python_docker_build.sh"'..done
Running 'docker exec -t b6a2c0 chmod +x /python_docker_build.sh'..done
Running 'docker exec -t b6a2c0 /python_docker_build.sh'.......................................................................................................................................................................done
Running 'docker cp b6a2c0:"/app.zip" "C:\Users\jmatson\AppData\Local\Temp\ynfbuvdk.pbu"'....done
Running 'docker kill b6a2c0'..done
Preparing archive...
Uploading 183.07 MB [#############################################################################]
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
Setting FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = ****
App setting AzureWebJobsStorage is different between azure and local.settings.json
Would you like to overwrite value in azure? [yes/no/show]
yes
Setting AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ****
Setting AWS_SECRET_KEY = ****
Syncing triggers...
Functions in httpGenGraph:
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the site was deleted at 2019-04-18 03:06:53 UTC and recreated with the same name at 2019-04-18 03:16:03 UTC

On app deletion all appsettings will be also be removed. Republishing should fix this for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but it hasn't worked. I just re-published with exactly the same command. It was successful, but there is no function code in Azure. Just an empty Function App ready for code / functions to be added. What is going on here? I can confirm the app settings/configuration values have updated, but no code/function has been uploaded (see original screenshot - it's the same thing again)

Comment: I see the publish was at 2019-04-20 00:35:49 UTC and the last time the site was accessed was at 2019-04-20 00:34:08 UTC.  Looks like the deployment hadn't actually completed when the site was last accessed. Please update if you are still not seeing the app contents.

Comment: I still see the same thing. I really am at a loss. It still says "You have created a function app! Now it is time to add your code..." even though I've uploaded a package with code etc. And when I first published it, it worked fine, it's only since re-publishing that it has vanished.

Comment: If you try to execute your function, does it work? I am trying to rule out some client side bug where it always show "time to add your code" even if you already have functions deployed.

Comment: I hadn't thought to try that, but without the code there I"m not sure of the URL to invoke the function. I tried re-publishing again as I think you get the URL endpoint at the end of publishing, but now getting this error Preparing archive...
Settings must be of the form "name=value".
Retry: 1 of 3
Settings must be of the form "name=value".
Retry: 2 of 3
Settings must be of the form "name=value".
Retry: 3 of 3
Settings must be of the form "name=value".

Answer (score 0):

From the back end , seen this operation

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it hasn't worked. I just re-published with exactly the same command. It was successful, but there is no function code in Azure. Just an empty Function App ready for code / functions to be added. What is going on here? I can confirm the app settings/configuration values have updated, but no code/function has been uploaded (see original screenshot - it's the same thing again)